# Flutter Build failed with an exception in Visual Studio

Tags: flutter, gradle

I purchased a food ordering app project and I am having errors building and running the app in my Visual Studio Code IDE...
I have updated the flutter SDK but still there are errors.

Please check the image attached to this
That is the error I get when I try to run the project....
help me. Thank you

2

> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Retrying Gradle Build: #9, wait time: 25600ms

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's no attached image you've mentioned in the question. Please, click on the `Edit` link below your question to add them. Also, It's better if you copy and paste the exception instead of a image.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to path  **project-folder/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

change this:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip

to this:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip

2- Go to path **project-folder/build.gradle**

change this:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

to this:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'

3- run these commands

> ```
> flutter clean
> ```

> ```
> flutter pub get
> ```

> ```
> flutter run
> ```